# Custom Injectable in nest.js

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I've created a simple logging service which provides debug-logging functionality via [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) behind the scenes that can be used as follows:

```
@Resolver('Category')
export class CategoryResolver {
  private log: DebugLog;

  constructor(private readonly categoryService: CategoryService, loggingService: LoggingService) {
    // needs this to determine logger prefix
    this.log = loggingService.getDebugLogger(this);
  }

  @ResolveProperty()
  async mainCategory(category: Category, args, context): Promise<MainCategory> {
    this.log('resolving mainCategory');
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Now, I'd like to get rid of the boilerplate code in the constructor, by creating an `@InjectLogger` decorator, similar to [`@InjectRepository` for `@nestjs/typeorm`](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/9895b27bc739ee3c1668389a24745cc520c500f9/lib/common/typeorm.decorators.ts). Basically I want to achieve being able to do this instead:

```
@Resolver('Category')
export class CategoryResolver {

  constructor(
    private readonly categoryService: CategoryService, 
    @InjectLogger(CategoryResolver) private readonly log: DebugLog
  ) { }

  @ResolveProperty()
  async mainCategory(category: Category, args, context): Promise<MainCategory> {
    this.log('resolving mainCategory');
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

How would I go about achieving something like this?

Answer (score 0):

`@nestjs/typeorm`'s `@InjectRepository()` injection works by adding a separate DI provider token for each registered entity - see the [`@nestjs/typeorm` providers](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/9895b27bc739ee3c1668389a24745cc520c500f9/lib/typeorm.providers.ts) for the provider logic. The logic iterates each registered `@Entity` and generates and adds a token provider for each.

To do something similar which matches your example, you will need to be able to identify and generate a token and associated provider for each type that you will pass as an argument to `@InjectLogger(<type>)`.

Comment: Hm shame... I don't see a way to know all the required loggers before they are being requested. I'd love to avoid having to put something like `LoggingModule.prepareLoggers([CategoryService, CategoryResolver, AnotherService, ...]` in my module init code...